# How can I ensure input is in the form #.##

Tags: python, error-handling, decimal, formatting, error-checking

I need to error check to ensure that user input has two decimal places.

How can I achieve this?

I ended up doing something like this:

```
 if len(input) > 3:
      if input[-3] == ".":
           #then the validation of the varriable
```

Comment: Regular expression? `len(number.split('.')[1]) == 2`? What are you trying to achieve, and where's your code so far?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want nothing but one number, decimal, and two numbers:

```
import re
s = '3.45'
if re.match("^\d{1}\.\d{2}$", s):
    print(s)
else:
    print('No match')
```

\d* matches no numbers or as many as you want. \d+ matches one number or as many as you want. \d{2} matches two numbers. ^ starts at the beginning, and $ ends at the end.

In Python 2x raw_input returns a string, and in Python 3x input does.